# Variable losing it value from atoi assignment

Tags: c, command-line, cs50

I'm new to C.

I am trying to take a number from a command line argument and use it in several calculations throughout the code.  The number input in the command line is obviously coming back as a string so I am trying to convert to a number to avoid all the calculation errors that come from using a char.

I haven't been taught atoi or stdlib.h so not even sure this is how I should be tackling this issue but it is the only way I could find to convert the string to a number.

When I declare a new variable `as = atoi(argv[1]);` and print it to verify all seems fine.

My code then does some other seemingly unrelated actions and when i printf my variable again the value is 0.  I don't understand why the value is changing when I am not re-declaring the variable but it means none of the calculations that follow will work.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: If I declare 'key' directly as an integer there are no issues with the program, the problem comes when I try to extract the integer from the array.  { is there after main() but it wouldn't format in the post.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
  string msg[0];
  int key = atoi(argv[1]);  
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("This function requires one command line argument: key\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (key < 1) {
    printf("error\n"); 
    return 1;
  }

  // At this point variable 'key' is ok and equals the value entered in command line
  msg[0] = get_string("text:");

  // After this point variable 'key' value is 0 unless I redeclare it
  int n = strlen(msg[0]);
```

Comment: What is the definition of `string`?  Is this really `C++`?

Comment: The next line after the `main()` signature should be `{`  Otherwise this will not compile.

Comment: @FiddlingBits It's probably the definition from `cs50.h` Just like `get_string()`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits `string` here is likely CS50's abomination `typedef char *string`.

Comment: `string msg[0];` reserves space for zero strings, you probably need `string msg[1];` to reserve space for one string. To access that one string, use `msg[0]`. Also note that if you don't need more than 1, the array is not necessary: `string msg;` works as effectively (there are a few *advanced* differences).

Comment: regarding: *string is coming from string.h*`  That is NOT true.  Rather `string` is coming from `cs50.h`.    This is yet another good reason to post a [mcve], that includes the `#include` statements for the needed header files

Comment: when posting code, indent EVERY line of code by an extra 4 spaces so stackoverflow treats those lines as code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're writing outside the bounds of the `msg` array.

```
string msg[0];
```

declares an array with no elements. So assigning to any element will write outside it, causing undefined behavior. That happens when you assign

```
msg[0] = get_string("text:");
```

You need to declare the array with the actual maximum number of elements you want to store in it. If you declare it as

```
string msg[10];
```

you can assign to `msg[0]` through `msg[9]`.